# How to change the input field color in Ionic 5 when focused?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework

I want to change the color of the input field, when it's focused. It's only that grey, when it gets focused by the following function and only as long as I don't type or click on the field.

```
export function autofocus() {
    let blanks = document.querySelectorAll(".blank")
    let textfield = document.getElementById("textfield")

    if (blanks.length > 0) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".blank")[0].setFocus()
    }
    else if (textfield) {
        document.getElementById("textfield").setFocus()
    }
}
```

[image]

The class that is responsible for it, is:

```
:host(.ion-focused) .item-native::after {
    background: var(--background-focused);
    opacity: var(--background-focused-opacity);
}
```

Unfortunately it's part of the Shadow DOM. Does anybody know, how to fix that? The opacity should be zero.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector and apply the CSS coloring rules? Querying the DOM and DOM manipulations are generally considered anti-pattern in React.

Comment: Tried that, but didn't work: https://prnt.sc/1ccg2hc. Do you know how to change the opacity variable itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
ion-item.ion-focused::part(native)::after {
    opacity: 0!important;
  }
```

Resources that helped me:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts